# how do I trim a word?

Tags: php, string

I want trim word by almost half for example

```
Washington
```

after trim it should be `washi`

```
Chicago
```

after trim it should be `chic`

```
Tokyo
```

after trim it should be `tok`

Comment: Exactly half would be easy, but what is "almost half"?

Comment: @BoltClock: how do you split "Tokyo" exactly in half?  Is there a unicode codepoint for "half a k"?

Comment: @Wooble: You could cut the 'k' in half vertically to get a 'v'.  :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Use [`substr()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to cut off unwanted part of the string.
2. Use [`strlen()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to calculate the length of the string.
3. Use [`ceil()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round a fraction up if the length is a odd number.

   ```
   $word = 'Tokyo';

   echo substr($word, 0, ceil(strlen($word) / 2));
   ```

If you're using Unicode then use [multibyte extension functions](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) as PHP doesn't support Unicode natively.

Answer (score 3):

```
$source = "Washington";

$word = substr($source, 0, ceil(strlen($source) / 2));
```

Try that..

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to trim them?

E.g. you could use `substr()`, to get the substring you like to have.

```
$ret = substr('Washington', 0, 5); // $res = Washi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function halfTrim($s) {
  return substr($s, 0, ceil(strlen($s)/2));
}
```